# when creating the genesis and Transaction using configtxgen do we need to use keypair

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I using the configtxgen to create the channeltx file and genesis Tx file. My question

- Do i need to provide the any keypair details when creating the
  genesisTx and channelTx.
- I am using the config.yaml file which has name and Id field as show
  in below code, where we will use this fields in fabric network.
- Do we need to add user keypair also in this config.yaml "MSPDir"
- where i can find the config.yaml file description.

  ```
  - &Org1
  # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
  # of the fabric.git development environment
  Name: Org1MSP

  # ID to load the MSP definition as
  ID: Org1MSP

  MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

  AnchorPeers:
      # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
      # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
      # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
      - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
        Port: 7051
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to create genesis, channeltx you will have to supply org msp, which contains public certificates

- admincerts
- cacerts
- tlscacerts

We don’t need to provide any key pair in the genesis configuration or channel configuration.

In fact for channeltx msp doesn’t require just policies alone enough